# Buttons access to dictionary data in correct order

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary, url

I have an array of buttons and a dictionary where `keys` are buttons' names and `values` are an `url` these buttons are meant to open.

All of these are sorted in correct order and the correct button name is displayed.

I am struggling to pass the correct `url` to the `openLink()` function tho.

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var links: [UIButton]!

let keysAndValues = ["Twitter" : "https://twitter.com/",
                       "Facebook" : "https://facebook.com/",
                       "YouTube" : "https://youtube.com/"]

func setButtonName() {

    let sortedDict = keysAndValues.sorted(by: <)
    let sortedButtons = links.sorted { $0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y }

    for (index, button) in sortedButtons.enumerated() {
        button.setTitle(sortedDict[index].key, for: UIControlState.normal)
    }
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let sortedDict = keysAndValues.sorted(by: <)
    let sortedButtons = links.sorted { $0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y }

    for (index, _) in sortedButtons.enumerated() {
        openLink(sortedDict[index].value)
    }
}
func openLink(_ link: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: "\(link)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }
}
```

How can I pass the correct `value` to `openLink(_ link: String)`? For now links are working in a random order.

PS: Every button is connected to `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction`

Comment: Dictionary data is not in any specific order. If you need order, use an array.

Comment: @rmaddy Why are the `keys` correctly sorted then when displayed as `button` titles?

Comment: Why does your `buttonTapped` method loop through all of the buttons and call `openLink` for all of them instead of just handling the button that was tapped?

Comment: I am trying to use a single method for every button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues is that for every button tap you call `openLink` for every button. Clearly you just want to call `openLink` for the one URL associated with the tapped button.

Rewrite your `buttonTapped` method as follows:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let title = sender.title(for: .normal)

    if let url = keysAndValues[title] {
        openLink(url)
    }
}
```

This gets the title of the tapped button and uses it as the key to retrieve the corresponding URL.

Comment: That works, but it's fragile since it uses user-visible information (The button title) to look up the URL. If you ever decide to change the button names in any way (adding a verb to the name, localizing for a different language, etc.) it will break. Instead I would suggest creating a dictionary that maps buttons to URLS and using the sender to look up the URL to open.

Answer (score 1):

rmaddy's solution works, but is fragile, for the reasons I mention in my comment. Instead of doing that, I'd suggest creating a dictionary keyed by the button.

Define an instance variable to hold your dictionary of URLs keyed by button:

```
var buttonURLsDict = [UIButton: String]()
```

And then modify your setButtonName method:

```
func setButtonName() {

    let sortedDict = keysAndValues.sorted(by: <)
    let sortedButtons = links.sorted { 
      $0.frame.origin.y < $1.frame.origin.y 
    }

    for (index, button) in sortedButtons.enumerated() {
        let title = sortedDict[index].key
        button.setTitle(title, for: UIControlState.normal)
        buttonURLsDict[button] = sortedDict[index].value
    }
}
```

And your IBAction method:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let url = buttonURLsDict[sender] else { return }
    openLink(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Duncan. I actually use `clear color` text in my app's buttons (over an imageView) so display wouldn't be a problem but your method has better logic overall I guess! Would adapting the code to a `UITableView` design be complicated?

Comment: In the case of a table view you typically have a data model that's arranged in an array (for a single section table view) or an array of arrays (for a sectioned table view.) In that case you usually use that array structure to hold things like a URL associated with each cell. Thus it's simpler than the case you're dealing with now.